# dumbbell glyphicon not working with shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Though plenty of glyphicons work, the dumbell is not one of them. Any ideas?

server.r

```
library(shinydashboard)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {})
```

ui.r

```
dashboardPage(
      title = "O8 Trainer",
      dashboardHeader(
        title = "Train!"
      ),
      dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
          menuItem("Trainer", 
          tabName = "trainTab", 
          icon = icon("dumbbell", lib = "glyphicon")) #"cog" works here, for instance.
        )
      )
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

Most answers link to the getbootstrap.com components page (including the icon vignette), but it is not clear where the list is on that page. The icons list on getbootstrap.com mostly contains icons that will not work with Shiny. Instead, I use [this list](https://www.w3schools.com/icons/bootstrap_icons_glyphicons.asp) and they all work well.

On that page only include the tail of the name of the icon. For instance, for icon name "glyphicon glyphicon-music", proper shiny code is:

```
icon("music", lib = "glyphicon")
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Original answer: the dumbbell icon is not available from the free iconset</strike>

The comments below are correct: using `icon()` is shiny only gives you access to whatever glyphicons are made available through bootstrap as per http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons

Comment: no, dumbbell is icon 357 of the 800 items included in the free set. On the left side of the main page, you can download all 800. I'll probably just end up embedding the raw png this way... Just wanted to see if I was missing something easy

Comment: To be more precise, `shiny` offers access to the set that can be found at http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons; see `?shiny::icon`.